# How vector class methods manipulating stack data

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, collections

`Stack` extends the `Vector` class, we know that, but if we create a `Stack` object

```java
Stack <Integer> st = new Stack<>()
```

how the inherited vector methods manipulate data inside the stack, when we call vector-defined methods like `add()`?

I tried, it's working but I didn't understand how it's working.

Comment: [dynamic dispatch (`wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

Comment: In brief: when a class inherits methods, it may override them. If it does, then _that_ method will be invoked (not the parent one, unless called via `super.thatMethod(...)`). This gets trickier with multiple inheritance of behavior from interfaces (e.g. now you can call `super.ParentInterface.someCommonMethod(...)`), but the notion is the same: you have a `Stack` object, so it will look in `Stack` first for `#someMethod`, followed by inherited classes.

Comment: Stack doesn't overide any of the vector inherited methods

Comment: In addition to the above, `Stack` and `Vector` are generally discouraged for use in any modern Java. You'd want `Deque` ("Deck") and `List`, respectively. A `LinkedList` is a `Deque`, a `Queue`, and a `List` all at the same time.